# Send packet to multiple out ports in a switch with NS3

Tags: simulation, multicast, ipv4, ns-3

Recently, I wanted to do some simulation with IPv4 switches.

And, there is a function that I do not know how to implement in the NS3.

When a switch receives a packet, it can send the packet out to multiple ports(replicate the packet).

It's sort of like multicast, but I don't want the complexity of the multicast. And I need some more freedom to choose the multiple out ports at runtime.

```
RouteInput  (Ptr<Packet> p, Ipv4Header &header, Ptr<const NetDevice> idev,
    UnicastForwardCallback ucb, MulticastForwardCallback mcb,
    LocalDeliverCallback lcb, ErrorCallback ecb)
```

I have tried to call "UnicastForwardCallback ucb" multiple times.
But it has some errors in the middle of the simulation.

```
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

Is there a way that I can achieve the things I want without using the multicast?
Or multicast is the only way?

Comment: more code can help, this error can be generated by many cases